# How to create new pandas dataframe column containing values of all other columns as a tensor?

Tags: python, pandas, pytorch

I'm trying to create a new feature column which is a tensor containing the values in the existing columns. So if col A's value is '1', col B's value is '0', and col C's value is 0, then the new feature column's value will be [1,0,0].

I tried the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import torch

df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[1,1,0], "B":[0,1,1], "Sentiment":[0,0,1]})

df["new_feature"] = [df["A"].values, df["B"].values, df["C"].values]
```

[image]

...but the result is not what I need. The result is getting the values down each column rather than the values across the row (multiple column values). For example, the `new_feature` column value for the first row should be [1,0,0] but its showing [1,1,0]

My ultimate aim is to get a dataframe column that I can use as a torch tensor to input into a neural net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`torch.from_numpy`](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/generated/torch.from_numpy.html) with `apply` lambda function.

```
df["new_feature"] = df.apply(lambda x:torch.from_numpy(x.to_numpy()), axis = 1)
df
   A  B  C                        new_feature
0  1  0  0  [tensor(1), tensor(0), tensor(0)]
1  1  1  0  [tensor(1), tensor(1), tensor(0)]
2  0  1  1  [tensor(0), tensor(1), tensor(1)]

df["new_feature"][0]
tensor([1, 0, 0])
```

First convert dataframe values to numpy array using [`pd.Series.to_numpy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_numpy.html#pandas-series-to-numpy) and
then convert numpy array to tensor using [`torch.from_numpy`](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/generated/torch.from_numpy.html).

Answer (score 0):

Do you want:

```
df['new_feature'] = df.values.tolist()
```

Output:

```
   A  B  C new_feature
0  1  0  0   [1, 0, 0]
1  1  1  0   [1, 1, 0]
2  0  1  1   [0, 1, 1]
```

Comment: Not a Pytorch expert but I somehow doubt that OP *should* want this. `df.values` already carries `new_feature.values`.